# What is the name hard plastic material that you find on bathroom cupboards?

Tags: bathroom, wood

Can someone tell me what the coating/covering is that you find on cabinets in a bathroom. It is a bit like vinyl or some sort of hard plastic. I was thinking vinyl but the coating seems harder and more like a plastic. I am building some cabinets and would like to use a similar finish.

[Here is an example](https://www.diy.com/departments/goodhome-garcinia-gloss-light-grey-integrated-handle-drawerline-door-drawer-front-w-300mm/5059340089188_BQ.prd)

Comment: Both answers below are correct, depending on what part of the cabinet you are asking about. Thermafoil is used on doors and drawer faces which have a profile, and melamine is used on the flat surfaces on the interior and exterior of the cabinet boxes or carcasses as it is known in the trade. It is finished on the cut edges with an edge banding of glue on or iron on material and trimmed to fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Melamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melamine) is one of several options for what you may be referring to. You can get sheets of plywood or MDF with melamine pre-laminated to them.

Answer (score 2):

It is called [thermafoil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermofoil).

A plastic layer applied with heat that takes on the shape of the substrate it is covering.

Great for easy cleaning. But not so great if it starts delaminating.

Also trying to paint over requires some extra work involving bonding primer.